# How to write and read data in txt file in java

Tags: java, swing, io

I am new to SO, I have designed a form in java, I added three buttons **Submit**, **Clear** and **Show Record**. I need to get data on submit event and pass it to txt file, and i want to show whole record on show record button click event. I need quick fix by you people, I am running out of time. Here is my Code:

```
import java.awt.*;  //import older gui library for content pane
import javax.swing.*;   //import newer gui library for labels, textfields, and button
import java.awt.event.*; //import gui event action library
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class CustomerRecord extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    // declare labels used on GUI screen
    private JLabel labelId, labelName, labelGender,labelcategory, labelPItem, labeldiscount;
    private JLabel labelError, labelRegistration; 
    private JTextField textId, textName, textGender, textState, textcategory, textPItem, textdiscount;
    // declare button used on GUI screen
    private JButton submitButton, clearButton, readButton;
    final JRadioButton jRadioMale = new JRadioButton("Male");
    final JRadioButton jRadioFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");
    // declare content pane
    private Container contentPane;

    public CustomerRecord() {
        createGUI();
    } // ends  constructor

    private void createGUI() {
        try {
            // get content pane and set the layout to null
            contentPane = getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(null);    //free-form layout
            setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.ITALIC, 14));

            // create the name label
            labelId = new JLabel(); //instantiate new JLabel
            labelId.setText("C.ID");    //set label text to name
            labelId.setLocation(38, 10);    //set location of JLabel
            labelId.setSize(200, 25);   //set size of JLabel
            labelId.setForeground(Color.BLACK);//set initial background color
            contentPane.add(labelId);   //add JLabel to content pane

            // create the name text box
            textName = new JTextField();    //instantiate new JTextField
            textName.setText("");   //clear JTextField
            textName.setToolTipText("Please enter ID");
            textName.setLocation(75, 10);   //set location of JTextFfield
            textName.setSize(200, 25);   //set size of JTextField
            contentPane.add(textName); //add jextfield to content pane

            // create the address label
            labelName = new JLabel();
            labelName.setText("Name:");
            labelName.setLocation(23, 50);
            labelName.setSize(80, 25);
            labelName.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            contentPane.add(labelName);

            // create the address text box
            textName = new JTextField();
            textName.setText("");
            textName.setToolTipText("Please type in full name");
            textName.setLocation(75, 50);
            textName.setSize(300, 25);
            contentPane.add(textName);
            labelGender = new JLabel();
            labelGender.setText("Gender");
            labelGender.setLocation(30, 90);
            labelGender.setSize(300, 25);
            labelGender.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            contentPane.add(labelGender);
            textGender = new JTextField();
            textGender.setText("");
            textGender.setToolTipText("M/F");
            textGender.setLocation(75, 90);
            textGender.setSize(130, 25);
            contentPane.add(textGender);
            labelcategory = new JLabel();
            labelcategory.setText("Category");
            labelcategory.setLocation(18, 170);
            labelcategory.setSize(300, 25);
            labelcategory.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            contentPane.add(labelcategory);
            textcategory = new JTextField();
            textcategory.setText("");
            textcategory.setToolTipText("Item Type (Grocery)");
            textcategory.setLocation(75, 170);
            textcategory.setSize(130, 25);
            contentPane.add(textcategory);
            labelPItem = new JLabel();
            labelPItem.setText("Total Item");
            labelPItem.setLocation(15, 210);
            labelPItem.setSize(250, 25);
            labelPItem.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            contentPane.add(labelPItem);
            textPItem = new JTextField();
            textPItem.setText("");
            textPItem.setToolTipText("Purchased items must be between start with 1 or 70");
            textPItem.setLocation(75, 210);
            textPItem.setSize(130, 25);
            contentPane.add(textPItem);
            labeldiscount = new JLabel();
            labeldiscount.setText("Discount");
            labeldiscount.setLocation(18, 250);
            labeldiscount.setSize(300, 25);
            labeldiscount.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            contentPane.add(labeldiscount);
            textdiscount = new JTextField();
            textdiscount.setText("");
            textdiscount.setToolTipText("Entered Value must be containing ' % '");
            textdiscount.setLocation(75, 250);
            textdiscount.setSize(130, 25);
            contentPane.add(textdiscount);
            submitButton = new JButton();
            submitButton.setText("Submit");
            submitButton.setToolTipText("Click \"submit \" when the form is completely filled out");
            submitButton.setLocation(125, 450);
            submitButton.setSize(100, 30);
            contentPane.add(submitButton);
            submitButton.addActionListener(this);
            readButton = new JButton();
            readButton.setText("Show Records");
            readButton.setToolTipText("Click Show Record if you want to check record");
            readButton.setLocation(225, 350);
            readButton.setSize(200, 30);
            contentPane.add(readButton);
            readButton.addActionListener(this);

            clearButton = new JButton();
            clearButton.setText("Clear");
            clearButton.setToolTipText("Click \"clear \" when you want to clear the form");
            clearButton.setLocation(250, 450);
            clearButton.setSize(100, 30);
            contentPane.add(clearButton);
            clearButton.addActionListener(this);

            // create the error label
            labelError = new JLabel();
            labelError.setText("Please correct items in red");
            labelError.setLocation(150, 500);
            labelError.setSize(190, 25);
            labelError.setForeground(Color.RED);
            labelError.setVisible(false);
            contentPane.add(labelError);

            // create the registration label
            labelRegistration = new JLabel();
            labelRegistration.setText("Thank you for your entry.");
            labelRegistration.setLocation(145, 500);
            labelRegistration.setSize(190, 25);
            labelRegistration.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            labelRegistration.setVisible(false);
            contentPane.add(labelRegistration);

            setTitle("Customer Form");  //set window title
            setSize(475, 600); //set window size
            setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }// ends creatGUI method.

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CustomerRecord application = new CustomerRecord();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }// ends main

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Submit")) {

                if (checkID() & checkName() & checkGender() &  check() & checkPItem() & checkdiscount()) {
                    labelRegistration.setVisible(true);
                    labelError.setVisible(false);    
                    submitButton.removeActionListener(this); 
                    clearButton.removeActionListener(this);  
                } else {
                    labelError.setVisible(true); 
                    labelRegistration.setVisible(false); 
                }
            } if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Clear")) 
                {
                textName.setText("");
                textName.setText("");
                textGender.setText("");
                textState.setText("");
                textcategory.setText("");
                textPItem.setText("");
                textdiscount.setText("");

                labelError.setVisible(false);
                labelRegistration.setVisible(false);
                labelId.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                labelName.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                labelGender.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                labelcategory.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                labelPItem.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                labeldiscount.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
    private boolean checkID() {
        if (textName.getText().length() == 0) {
            labelId.setForeground(Color.RED);   //name is not correct
            return false;
        } else {
            labelId.setForeground(Color.BLACK); //name is correct
            return true;
        }
    } 
    private boolean checkName() {
        if (textName.getText().length() < 5) {
            labelName.setForeground(Color.RED); 
            return false;
        } else {
            labelName.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            return true;
        }
    } 

    private boolean checkGender() {
        if (textGender.getText().length() == 0) {
            labelGender.setForeground(Color.RED);
            return false;
        } else {
            labelGender.setForeground(Color.BLACK); 
            return true;
        }
    } 
    private boolean check() {
        try {

            if (textcategory.getText().length() == 5) {
                labelcategory.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                return true;
            } else {
                labelcategory.setForeground(Color.RED); 
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            labelcategory.setForeground(Color.RED);     
            return false;
        }
    } 
    private boolean checkPItem() {

            if (textPItem.getText().startsWith("1") || textPItem.getText().startsWith("70")) 
            {
                labelPItem.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                return true;
            } else {
                labelPItem.setForeground(Color.RED);    
                return false;
            }      
    } 
    private boolean checkdiscount() {
        if (textdiscount.getText().contains("%"))
        {
            labeldiscount.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                return true;
        } else
        {
            labeldiscount.setForeground(Color.RED); 
                return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: the best thing to start with is seperation of your code. Ideally, you would have the code to handle the txt files (reading, writing, ... ) in a separate layer, but at the very least, in a different java class. That would make it a lot easier to read, not to mention test. You also would be able to unit test the class without having to keep the UI in mind as well.
also: beware of code like this: catch (Exception e) { }
hiding exceptions (especially during development) is about the worst thing you can do.

Comment: Explore `java.io` package.

Comment: refer this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Take a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: I looking for quick fix in code, I will read these blogs latter, currently I am running out of time

Comment: do a search for java io or even search using the exact text of your answer and I am sure you will find plenty of tutorials

Comment: Maybe [this will help](http://www.studygs.net/timman.htm)

Comment: *"I need quick fix by you people, I am running out of time."*  Plan your time better. This is not our problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about us making up for the OP's poor time-management skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I provide an answer corrected some of the codes you have mistakenly done.

## Please check the area where I corrected.

Your code:

```
    // create the name text box
        textName = new JTextField();    //instantiate new JTextField
        textName.setText("");   //clear JTextField
        textName.setToolTipText("Please enter ID");
        textName.setLocation(75, 10);   //set location of JTextFfield
        textName.setSize(200, 25);   //set size of JTextField
        contentPane.add(textName); //add jextfield to content pane
```

Modified Code:

```
    // create the name text box
        textId = new JTextField();    //instantiate new JTextField
        textId.setText("");   //clear JTextField
        textId.setToolTipText("Please enter ID");
        textId.setLocation(75, 10);   //set location of JTextFfield
        textId.setSize(200, 25);   //set size of JTextField
        contentPane.add(textId); //add jextfield to content pane
```

============================
Then I defined new two methods for read file and for write to file

## This is Writing to file

```
      private void writeToFile(String list) throws IOException{
///
                File f = new File("E:\\test1.txt");
                System.out.println(f);
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f,true);
                System.out.println(fw);
                try{
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    System.out.println(bw);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(list);
                    bw.flush();
                    bw.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                ///
}
```

## This is read File

private void readFile(){

```
     File f = new File("E:\\test1.txt");
try{
       FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
       while(br.ready()){
       System.out.println(br.readLine());
        }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

Then added new if statement in side the actionPerforemed(ActionEvent e) to handle the event from "Show Records" Button where you have not added it. in side it I call the readFile() which will print the all line from reading file.(This reading file is same file where you going to write.)

```
         //Newly added event for Show Records button. 

        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Show Records")) {
           readFile();
        }
```

Then in side the actionPerforemed(ActionEvent e) and in the if statement related to submit button

## Added Following Code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Submit")) {

            if (checkID() & checkName() & checkGender() & check() & checkPItem() & checkdiscount()) {
                labelRegistration.setVisible(true);
                labelError.setVisible(false);
                //concatnating the collected data to be written.
                String toBewrite = textId.getText() + "," + textName.getText();
                toBewrite = toBewrite + "," + textGender.getText() + "," + textcategory.getText();
                toBewrite = toBewrite + "," + textPItem.getText() + "," + textdiscount.getText();
                ///calling the writeToFile method where the relavent data to be updated to the file.
                writeToFile(toBewrite);
                ////
                submitButton.removeActionListener(this);
                clearButton.removeActionListener(this);
            } else {
                labelError.setVisible(true);
                labelRegistration.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Clear")) {
            textName.setText("");
            textName.setText("");
            textGender.setText("");
            textState.setText("");
            textcategory.setText("");
            textPItem.setText("");
            textdiscount.setText("");

            labelError.setVisible(false);
            labelRegistration.setVisible(false);
            labelId.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            labelName.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            labelGender.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            labelcategory.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            labelPItem.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            labeldiscount.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        }
        //Newly added event for Show Records button.
        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Show Records")) {
            readFile();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First let me point out some faulty (but not deadly) design. All your `checkXxx()` methods handle the obtaining of the text from the fields. I would change them to accept Strings as arguments. The reason is that you are going to need those String values from the text fields in the scope of the `actionPerformed`, in order to save them to your text file.

> **I need to get data on submit event and pass it to txt file**

You should use a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) and use this constructor

> `public FileWriter(String fileName,
>                    boolean append)
>                    throws IOException` - 
>   Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.

that will allow you to append to the file with one of its `append` methods.

> **and i want to show whole record on show record button click event**

Not sure if you mean you want to read *all* the records or read a single record based of a name or something. For the former, text components have a [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to read an entire document onto the text component (say a text area). For the latter, you are going to need to read line by line and check if some part of the line matches the data you want to match. This is basic io stuff. You can read more at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). For example, something like (assuming your records/lines are comma separated values):

```
BufferedReader reader = new Bufferedreader(new FileReader(new File("file")));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    String firstName = tokens[0].trim();
    if (firstName.equals(firstNameFieldtext)) {
        // use the tokens to populate the fields.
        break;
    }
}
reader.close();
```

The above code just reads line by line, splitting each line into an array. It checks the first token to see if a name matches a field value. If it does, then you can use the values form the array to populate the fields.

If you wanted to read the whole file onto a text area, you could simple pass the same `BufferedReader` to the `read` method like `textArea.read(reader, null);`